# Smarty sql with controller

Tags: php, pdo, smarty

Hello i have a problem with smarty, i can't get pdosql normally working.

But i need `panel_content` change with function `eval(stripslashes($panel.panel_content))` and i don't know how.

Controller -

```
<?php
$panel_info = $db->getRows("SELECT panel_name, panel_filename, panel_content, panel_type, panel_access, panel_url_list panel_restriction, panel_show_name, panel_class FROM ".DB_PREFIX."panels WHERE panel_side = '4' AND panel_status = '1' ORDER by panel_order ASC");

$smarty->assign('panel_info',$panel_info);

//Tested something.... but it didn't work

foreach($panel_info = $panels) {
$panel['name'] = $panels['panel_name'];
$panel['content'] = $panels['panel_content'];
$panel['class'] = $panels['panel_class'];
$panel['show_name'] = $panels['panel_show_name'];
$smarty->assign("panel_name", "{$panel['name']}", true);
$smarty->assign("panel_content", "{$panel['content']}", true);
$smarty->assign("panel_class", "{$panel['class']}", true);
$smarty->assign("panel_show_name", "{$panel['show_name']}", true);
}
?>
```

TPL

```
{foreach $panel_info as $panel} 
                 <aside class="{$panel.panel_class} aside section">
                    <div class="section-inner">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2 class="heading {$panel.panel_show_name}">
                        {if $panel.panel_name != ''}
                        {$panel.panel_name}
                        {/if}
                        </h2>
                        {$panel.panel_content}
                        </div><!--//content-->  
                    </div><!--//section-inner-->                 
                </aside><!--//aside-->
{$panel_name}
{foreachelse}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Two questions. Whats the sense of the foreach inside the php file and why do you want to evalute the panel_content field. Does it contain smarty or php code?

Comment: I wanna load widgets from sql and from file if($panel_file != 'none') {
include "file.php";
} else {
$panel_content = "Selected from sql";
}

And i don't wanna enable php in tpl file.